# Calculating eigenvectors for PCA and obtaining a different result from Matlab/EViews

Tags: pca, matlab, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, eviews

Based on the variance-covariance matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}0.62 & 0.62\\ 0.62 & 0.72\end{pmatrix},$$ I have calculated the following eigenvalues $$λ_1 = 0.0500, \;λ_2 = 1.2840.$$ I then calculated the respective eigenvectors: $[-0.9206, 1]$ and $[1, 1.0846]$.

However, in MATLAB and EViews the eigenvectors are $[-0.7352, 0.6779]$ and $[0.6779, 0.7352]$. The ratio between my eigenvectors and that in MATLAB and EViews is exactly the same, but the numbers are clearly different, which affects the results slightly.

To solve for the eigenvector, I substituted one of the unknowns for $1$ for simplicity. MATLAB and EViews have substituted $0.6779$ instead, but I am wondering how this number is calculated?

Comment: Matlab, EViews softwares calculates(better to say they try to find) the eigenvectors with unit norm and orthogonality constrain( here you have symmetric matrices,so it will be orthogonal anyways). I didn't get what do you want to get? But if you want to change the vectors to with one element 1 you need to solve the equations which map your eigen vectors to your desired form

Comment: Take your eigenvectors and divide them by their norm (length). You will get Matlab's ones.